# Insert executes twice, VB

Tags: vb.net

My insert statement always executes twice, this is my code:

```
Private Sub NewEmployee()
    Dim MS As New MemoryStream
    Dim Images() As Byte

    If (pbEmpPhoto.Image IsNot Nothing) Then
        pbEmpPhoto.Image.Save(MS, pbEmpPhoto.Image.RawFormat)
        Images = MS.GetBuffer
        MS.Close()
    End If


    ' Adds Parameters
    Access.AddParam("@empid", tbEmpID.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@lname", tbLastName.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@fname", tbFirstName.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@address", tbAddress.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@contact", tbContact.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@dept", cbDept.SelectedItem)
    Access.AddParam("@position", cbPosition.SelectedItem)
    Access.AddParam("@emppic", IIf(pbEmpPhoto.Image IsNot Nothing, Images, DBNull.Value))

    ' Execute Insert Command
    Access.ExecQuery("INSERT INTO EmployeeInfo (EmployeeID,Fname,Lname,Address,[Contact],Department,[Position],EmployeePic) VALUES (@empid,@fname,@lname,@address,@contact,@position,@dept,@emppic); ")

    ' Reports And Aborts on Errors
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Access.Exception) Then MsgBox(Access.Exception) : Exit Sub
    ' Success Message
    MessageBox.Show("Registration Successful!", "New Employee", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)


    RG.RefreshGrid()
    pbEmpPhoto.Image = Nothing
    Exit Sub
    Me.Close()


End Sub
```

Access came from a class that i created, here's where it executes the sub:

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    NewEmployee()
End Sub
```

How can i fix this kind of problem? Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Me.Close will never be called as you are exiting the sub... Also you can Create a Boolean and set it to true the first time around, then check it if it's true and if so don't call your method. I have a feeling you are leaving code out that's the problem.

Comment: I just recently inserted it there because i think it doesn't proceed to ending it's sub. Thanks for the suggestion, i'll try it and update you if there's a improvement. Thanks! PS. Where should i put the boolean?

Comment: Are there other instances that you are calling `NewEmployee()`? You can right-click the sub then `Find All References`.

Comment: There's only 1 match found. I even double checked the whole class, there's nothing else.

Comment: In that case, stepping through the code is the best way. Put a breakpoint then debug it.

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll try that later.